# Is it acceptable to ask an estranged former colleague to 'siezen' even if you previously 'duzen-ed'?

Tags: colleagues, germany, relationships, ex-colleagues

*Note: My native language is English which lacks a T-V distinction*

Generally, when two adult German speakers meet in the workspace, they start by '*siezen-ing*' (speaking German with the use of the formal pronoun '*Sie*') and then at some point the more 'senior' of the two will offer to switch to '*duzen-ing*' (speaking German with the informal pronoun '*du*') which will generally be accepted by the more junior colleague. I understand that once two speakers are on a '*duzen*' level relationship, that relationship is generally persistent and that is largely considered inappropriate/impolite to revert to a '*siezen*' level relationship. How persistent is that relationship? In particular, how does it apply to ex-colleagues (once you no longer share an employer)?

If as a result of the departure of one of the colleagues, the two colleagues become on a similar level, can the previously more junior colleague insist on the use of '*Sie*' to reset the relationship?

Comment: This question has little to do with work and more to do with specific conventions of the German language, so I think it would be more appropriate to ask it in the German language section of the site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the workplace, it’s about social relations with an ex coworker.

Comment: FWIW, "estranged" usually implies some kind of conflict between the two parties. If you're just asking about two people who no longer work together, it doesn't really fit here.

Comment: I understand that there is some German culture specific issues here, but really this question is no different than going from Mr/Ms to a first name basis.

Comment: @SquiddleXO While the German language has a *name* for the concept, it does exist in many other languages, including English. "Being on first name basis" vs "being on last name basis" is the exact same concept, it just doesn't have a simple name in English, only this clunky description.

Comment: I am with @Hilmar's answer, "seniority" is not the criterion over all others to tell whether Du or Sie is used. *"can the previously more junior colleague insist on the use of 'Sie' to reset the relationship?"* - I wonder why the junior should want to change back to a much more distant relation, now when they are on a similar level?

Comment: Sounds kinky...

Answer (score 10):

I don't live in Germany, but I'm familiar with the language, and my native language has a similar concept.

When you switched from "Sie" to "du", it meant that your relationship reached a certain level of confidence. It is a mark that the senior considers the junior at least a little bit more than just another employee in the same company, under him/her or not.

In my experience, the proposition of "dutzen" typically comes during or after an informal talk or occasion. For instance if you discussed some personal things during a coffee break, or did something not work-related together. It is often unrelated to the hierarchy of the company. If big bosses are not "dutzing" with interns, it is not only because of the rank difference, it is because they have less occasions to socialize together, hence to create the non-work sort of relationship that is required for "dutzen".

**To summarize, "dutzen" means that the two persons know and appreciate each other at least a little bit personally, not only professionally.**

So, because it is not a mark of seniority or rank, changing roles in the company, or leaving the company, should not be a reason to change "dutzen" back to "Siezen".

Is it possible to go back to Siezen then? The only reason that would not seem too strange to me would be if you were in personal conflict with the person.

Comment: Indeed. Going from siezen to duzen is an explicit downgrade of the relationship and is received as such. Not advisable unless there was a strong reason to do so (a falling out etc.). It's quite a strong measure saying: "stay away from me from now on, and keep formal."

Comment: In small companies the Du is standard from first day of work. Depends on the company.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I think you might have inadvertently swapped "from" and "to" there.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I think you accidentally switched it around. "Duzen" is an upgrade in familiarity and going *back* to siezen is something I would expect after two people that knew each other well were involved in a lawsuit or one cheated on the other with the wife or a similar breach of trust.

Comment: @nvoigt Oh yes, you are completely right. I meant going from "duzen" to "siezen" is a downgrade of the relationship.

Answer (score 6):

> can the previously more junior colleague insist on the use of 'Sie' to reset the relationship?

You can but unless there was some sort of incident that would be perceived as very rude or offensive.

You overstating the "seniority" aspect. German formality in the workplace is a lot less than it was 20 years ago and "Du" is quite common these days even in situations where the persons don't know each particularly well and it's often the default mode if you meet someone new in a casual setting.

Going back to "Sie" would be unusual and certainly raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 1):

In Dutch the equivalents of Sie/du are u/jij. Personally I think it's quite strange to go back to "u" when you have already jij-ed each other. I have only seen it happen when two people have had a conflict of some sort with each other and are putting some distance between each other.

Comment: Linguists will agree that Dutch has the same Germanic T/V distinction, but sociologists will point out that it is used differently. And this question really is about the social side of the German T/V distinction. As an example of the social side, consider the question how the presence of a third person matters for the T/V distinction.